# Is there a method in JavaScript to get a representation of a really big number of type BigInt in a relatively quick time?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As an experiment, I calculated `60000!` (factorial) in JavaScript using `BigInt`. It took about 3.8 seconds. To show some (or any) representation of the result, I just showed the first 10 digits on screen, using

```
result.toString().slice(0, 10)
```

But to my surprise, this operation took close to 4 seconds and is blocking all UI of the browser (Google Chrome). (I did have some mechanism to yield processor time during the calculation of the factorial, so that wasn't blocking the UI).

Is there some way to show a representation of this number fast?

Additional info: `result.toString().length` is `260630`. If this number was shown on the page, it won't wrap to the next line, and the Chrome tab might freeze, as it was trying to create a page with the width suitable to fit in this number.

Comment: This might just be the overhead of having a 200KB string in memory. Not sure how that can be sped up if that's the case.

Comment: somehow the whole calculation took about the same time as this string operation... the native code of BigInt multiplication seems really fast relatively speaking

Comment: There is also the overhead of converting a huge number from its binary representation to a decimal one. This does not go for free either. When I did `toString(2).slice(0, 10)` I got the result almost immediately (as no base-conversion needed).

Comment: good... if I do `console.log(now = performance.now(), foo.toString() && false, performance.now() - now)` it shown it was taking about 3.6 seconds, and `console.log(now = performance.now(), foo.toString(2) && false, performance.now() - now)` shown that it took about 4/1000 of a second

Comment: That's what I saw. I think this is clearly the main factor in the slowing down of the output (the decimal conversion). I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why the output of the number (or only its first 10 digits) takes that much time is that the number must be converted to a decimal representation. This is a huge calculation, involving shifts of many thousands of bytes, subtractions of big numbers, with a cary passing through that many bytes, and all that repeated thousands of times.

If you replace the outputting code with:

```
result.toString(2).slice(0, 10)
//             ^^
```

... you'll see a drastic improvement in speed. The reason is that for this operation no base conversion is needed, and the string can be built in linear time (in terms of the number of bytes).

Comment: good, I am planning to use `result.toString(2).length` as it is `865793` which looks easier to identify (that the right answer was obtained) that if it is first 10 binary digits such as `1001000011`