# Is there a reason why arbitrary precision arithmetic (such as BigInt in JavaScript) is implemented in binary?

Tags: v8, bigint, arbitrary-precision

From [this question, it seems Google Chrome and Node.js both chose to implement arbitrary precision arithmetic in binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522790/is-there-a-method-in-javascript-to-get-a-representation-of-a-really-big-number-o).  Is there a good reason to do that?

If we can add, subtract, multiply, or divide, and do 7 + 8 = 15 and carry to the next digit, it is faster than doing it bit by bit, with 7 + 8 needing to add two bits 4 times.

Comment: "Binary" does not mean "bit by bit". It might be done 64 bits at a time on a 64 bit processor, or even more if using SIMD instructions.

Comment: I guess that's why I bombed the interview when I was asked to do addition or "plus 1" in an interview and I did it by decimal digits

Comment: Typically BigNum libs optimize for calculation speed, not output. Since the machine internal number repr is binary, it is much faster to calc with int32/int64 as digits in an array. Calculation with real decimal digits in memory would be much slower (+plus more complicated in digit carry handling and such, the reason why computers moved to binary in the first place in the 50s). Downside - the output actually needs decimal digits - now the whole number has to be divmod'ed by 10 to get those digits.

Answer (score 3):

V8 developer here. Binary is a good choice because hardware is binary [*]. That doesn't mean that operations happen one bit at a time. In V8, a BigInt's "digits" are `uintptr_t` values, i.e. register-sized (32 bit on a 32-bit machine, 64 bit on a 64-bit machine) unsigned integers. See [our blog post](https://v8.dev/blog/bigint) for an overview, and [the source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/objects/bigint.cc) for all the gory details. FWIW, many other implementations (e.g. GMP, OpenJDK, Go, Dart) have made the same basic choice.

[*] Some hardware architectures have instructions for "binary coded decimal" arithmetic, which is similar to what you're describing, but this approach is (1) generally considered less efficient, and (2) not available on all architectures that we want V8 to run on.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer: it is done by adding two 32 or 64 bit integer together, so it is faster than doing it one decimal digit at a time.

To get the result of a multiplication, probably in one machine code cycle, two 64 bit integers can multiply and all digits of the result can be obtained.